# git ignore specific file in subdirectory

Tags: git

I have a .gitignore file in the root of a git repository on my Windows machine and I'd like to ignore a specific file located in a subdirectory (several levels down from the root). Is this how I specify the file I want to ignore in .gitignore?

path/to/file/myignoredfile.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/path/to/file/myignoredfile.txt
```

to be precise. Please note the initial slash. It means "start traversing from the directory where this .gitignore resides".